# Http failure during parsing url

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use an Angular service to display some data on the front of my application.

In match.service.ts:

```
 let url = `/app/match/${matchId}/embeddable`;
 return this.httpClient.get(url)
}
```

In match.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.eventsSubscription = this.events.subscribe(id => {
      this.matchId = id;
      this.matchService.getMatchInfo(this.matchId).subscribe(match => {
        this.status = match['status']; 
    this.matchService.getMatch(this.matchId).subscribe(res => {
      console.log('hello there');
      console.log(res);
});
```

This is the expected result:

127.0.1:8000/app/match/1/embeddable
[image: 127.0.0.1:8000/app/match/1/embeddable]

On postman:
[image]

These are the headers:

[image]

But this is the error I get:

[image]

I don't understand why the compiler fails to parse the route, I would appreciate some help with this!

Comment: try setting reponseType on get request.
`return this.httpClient.get(url),{responseType: 'text'}`

Comment: @AmeerPappay Thank you for your response! Adding the response type worked, and I get the same response I got on postman! but my real response type is a video

Comment: @yosra You can set the response type as blob, and then convert it to video file var `blob = new Blob([response.blob()], {type: 'video/mp4'});`

Comment: @GopeshSharma can you please tell me how to use it? I've tried ```  getMatch(matchId : number): Observable<any> {
    let url = `/app/match/${matchId}/embeddable`;
    return this.httpClient.get(url,{responseType:'blob'})
      .pip(
        map(res => {
          let blob = new Blob([res.blob()], {type: 'video/mp4'});
        }))
  }```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve, play the video or download the video?

Comment: @GopeshSharma I ant to play the video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the response type as a blob, and then convert it to the video file as shown below. After that, you need to attach the URL to the video source.

```
let videofile = {};
let url = `/app/match/${matchId}/embeddable`;
this.httpClient.get(url,{responseType:'blob'}) 
    .subscribe(data => videofile = this.getVideoFile(data),
               error => console.log("Error downloading the file."),
               () => console.log('Completed file download.'));

getVideoFile(data: Response) {
  const blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'video/mp4'});
  const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  return url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add response type with your get request : -

`return this.httpClient.get(url,{responseType: 'text'})`

Comment: Thanks but as I said in the comments the responseType I'm interested in is video/mp4